# windows and macintosh show differently a page

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

I have the following http://jsbin.com/ojeja4/2/edit

The button and the expiration date working correct in windows, in *all browsers* but in OS X in *safari & firefox* (and maybe others) I find out that the button and the expiration date isn't correct.

Below I have print screens:

**Windows - Firefox and all other browsers**

[image]

**OS X - Firefox**

[image]

**OS X - Safari versions 3,4,5**

[image]

I really can't understand what is the problem. I tried use position instead of margin and padding but the result still the same. I found a jquery script and I [used it](http://jsbin.com/ojeja4/edit), which recognize the os and browser, but I don't see the reason for a css problem to use a jquery script.
Is it a common problem between windows and os x or I did a mistake in code that I can't understand?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *could* be because of the font. Your are using Arial on Windows and Helvetica on Mac. Try using a cross operating system font. Or maybe something like Google Font API.

Comment: good thought, you inspired me. I set fixed heights for the divs and now works correctly.